# compile LESS with custom parameters using Assetic

Tags: less, symfony-2.1, assetic, lessphp

I want to compile a LESS file with parameters fetched from the database.

So something like this:

```
$color = "#433332";
```

And then in .less

```
@baseColor: $color;
```

Of course this is just pseudocode, so give you an idea what I want to do.

I am using Assetic, Symfony 2.1.8-DEV and the leafo/lessphp bundle.

I have no idea how I could achieve this. Is it even possible?

Comment: no this is not possible, not with normal LESS and not with assetic LESS (because assetic uses the normal LESS)

Comment: Is somehow possible to write a wrapper or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could possibly define a parameter at runtime based on a db value and pass it into your assetic configuration and through to LESS as a global var (or similar), but configuration is parsed pretty early on and that would probably be a bit mental. I certainly wouldn't rule it out as possible though, I'm pretty sure I've seen a hack to achieve this using the regular SASS compiler.

The following PR on GitHub may be of relevance:

https://github.com/kriswallsmith/assetic/pull/177